# Formal definition of Machine Learning given Classification as Example

Tags: algorithms, regression, machine-learning

I have tried to write some easy but formal definition of a machine learning model using a classification task as example and I need some review.

The goal of machine learning is:

$arg min_{\Theta}(c(\textbf y,\hat{\textbf y})|o)$

$c(.) \in C$ = Cost Function of a set of Cost Functions$

$f(.) \in F$ = Function (Machine Learning Model) of a set of Functions$

$o(.) \in O$ = Optimizer of a set of Optimizers$

$\hat{y} = f(\textbf x,\Theta) =$ Predicted Value

$y =$ True Value

$\textbf x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ = d-dimensional Datapoint$

$\Theta \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ = m-dimensional Parameter Vector$

Here, given the dataset $\mathbf X$ for a chosen Classifier $f(.) \in F$ the Optimizer $o(.) \in O$ is used to find the Parameter Vector $\Theta \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ for the $f(.) \in F$ such that the Cost function $c(.) \in C$ is minimized.

I am happy for any comments!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "$arg min_{\Theta}(c(\textbf y,\hat{\textbf y})|o)$"? Did you mean "the goal is to minimize $c(\textbf y,\hat{\textbf y})$ wrt $o$"?

Comment: You have two options for the function(s) : either you consider a single function $f : x, \Theta \mapsto f( x,\Theta)$, or you consider a parametrized family $F$ of functions, say $F = \{f_\Theta \ \big| \ \Theta \in \mathbb{R}^m\}$.

Comment: Hello thank you. I mean I choose a cost function c from a family of cost functions and I want to minimize this cost cost function which takes as parameters the predicted and true values given an optimization algorithm o. The predicted y which results in the smallest error are achieved with the optimal model parameters theta

Comment: The pairs $(x,y)$ vary among a lot of possibilities. The first task should be to suggest a definition for "the parameters $\Theta$ are better than the parameters $\Theta'$", write $\Theta < \Theta'$ in this case. eg $\Theta > \Theta' : \Longleftrightarrow \Theta$ has better accuracy than $\Theta'$.

Comment: Oh, and the optimizer definitely shouldn't *belong* to the definition, but ratter rely on the definition.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have c and o as part of the definition since they are not learned during training but are chosen in advance. The same is true for the model f as well as for the total data X, hence the only thing which is optimized are the parameters.  Do you know another source where machine learning is formally defined in mathematical terms

Comment: I really enjoyed this paper : [Learnability can be undecidable](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42256-018-0002-3). I'm sure you'll find numerous ideas there.